# JAX-WS client Request STS without wsdl, ntlm protocol - Java

Tags: java, web-services, mule, cxf, jax-ws

I am having trouble requesting claims from an Secure Token Service.

My setup is the following:
I have to call an ADFS(in production where the wsdl is supplied) to get a claim which i can use to call another service that gives me a key to request information from the provider. But in the test environment I am given a STS service which resembles ADFS but it does not supplies a wsdl, it does simple not have a wsdl I am told. So the only information I am given is that I have to call the STS the `kerberos`, `ntlm` or `username` way. So my question is, how do I do this when I have no wsdl?

I am given an URL to call such as `https://server:port/ActiveSts/ntlm` or `https://server:port/ActiveSts/username` these are the choices I can choose between to request a token. I have tried something like this:

```
    SpringBusFactory springBusFactory = new SpringBusFactory();
    Bus bus = springBusFactory.createBus();

    STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(bus);
    stsClient.setLocation("https://server:port/ActiveSts/username");
    stsClient.setSoap12();
    stsClient.setKeyType(STSConstants.BEARER_KEY_KEYTYPE);


    bus.setProperty(SecurityConstants.STS_CLIENT, stsClient);
    //bus.setProperty(SecurityConstants.STS_APPLIES_TO, "https://server:port/ActiveSts/username");      
    bus.setProperty(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, "username");
    bus.setProperty(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD, "password");        

    SecurityToken securityToken = stsClient.requestSecurityToken();

    System.out.println(securityToken.toString());
```

But it does not work, and all the relevant stuff I find when searching the web includes a `wsdl` to be used.

**EDIT-1:**
The error that we encounter right now:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The
>   server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. 
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.    at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:849)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1515)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:855)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:52)
>     at testwebservice.testprogram.main(testprogram.java:43)

Comment: Could you give a little more information beyond "it does not work"? i.e. a stacktrace, errormessage/code, and so on?

Comment: The code at the top is the code we use, just replaced with the correct server and port.

Comment: At the top of the stacktrace you can read what you should do to get more information as "internal error" is overly broad to have a guess. Perhaps the additional information you'll get this way will help you to solve your problem on your own. Otherwise just come back with the details.